# Saving excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I created the application with addins and ribbon.
Here is my code. I want to save only data in excel sheet with the filename entered by user.

```
 SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();              
 saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
 Globals.Sheet1.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 Globals.Sheet1.Application.Quit();
```

The file gets saved with this code. But when I opened the file, the data is also saved in the file. But I get the error when I opened the file - .vsto file did  no succeed.
Can anybody help me what is wrong here? What to do to avoid this error message?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: which version of excel? and what is the error message? could you provide more details?

Comment: Error is Installing office customization - .vsto file did not succeed. Details are - ************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading file:///C:/Users/Rupali/Desktop/NetsuiteTMDItemUpload.vsto did not succeed. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
I am running it in debug mode